# How to take middleware on one function on route ressource (laravel)

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes, middleware

I want take auth middleware on only create, update, delete route ressource. I know how to do with simple route, so, i don't know with ressource route.

```
Route::resource('cars', CarController::class);
Route::get('/cars/{car}/delete', [CarController::class, 'softdelete'])->name('cars.softdelete')->middleware('auth');

Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth'])->name('dashboard');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put the middleware on your controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
        $this->middleware('auth')->except(['index','show']);
        // OR
        $this->middleware('auth')->only(['store','update','edit','create']);
}
```

Comment: good solution, you can do the same in your routes too.

Comment: Thanks you ! this is exactly what I needed !

Answer (score 0):

You can do that if you define the resource route with and without middleware separate: (quick example of the idea)

```
Route::resource('cars', CarController::class, [
        'only' => [
            'index',
            'show'
        ]
    ]);

Route::resource('cars', CarController::class, [
        'except' => [
            'index',
            'show'
        ]
    ])
    ->middleware([ 'auth']);
```

Comment: Thanks you, but I have the impression that the tirka method is better because there is no need to rewrite all the routes

Comment: That is a choice, I try to keep the middleware in the route file as much as possible.  But I do not use the resource routes either. Both methods are good. Maybe accept the answer from  tirta keniten , if that did the trick.